# Setting maxLength when using Sencha GXT

Tags: extjs, gwt, gxt

I am using Sencha GXT 3.1.1 to use it with GWT. Now I should limit the size of TextFields by using the `maxLength` attribute of HTML.

First of all, I haven't found any possibility to do that directly in this class, with `setMaxLength()` method.

Can anybody help how to use the `maxlength` attribute inside Sencha GXT classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way, but it's a bit of a hack:

```
textField.getCell()
    .getAppearance()
    .getInputElement(textField.getElement())
    .setAttribute("maxLength", "3");
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this until I find time to go back to this project.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

```
InputElement inputElement = textField.getElement()
        .select("input")
        .getItem(0)
        .cast();
inputElement.setMaxLength(valueMaxLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this problem is using a validator.

```
myTextField.addValidator(new MaxLengthValidator(3));
```

This validator will check if the value of the TextField has more than three letters. If it has more than three letters it will show an error.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The Validator is a goog idea I think. But it doesn't prevent the user from typing in longer values.

Comment: That's correct. But it ensures, that longer values will be recognized as errors. The solution that was posted by Guilliaume is also a way to solve your request. But keep in mind, you are dealing with the html elements and in case that sencha changes something on the appearance - with a new release - you might run into trouble.

Comment: You also can add a KeyDownHandler to your field and cancel the keydown event if more than three letters are entered.